# Syntax error by using apostrophe in single quote

Tags: python

Print the quote

> Allah said,"Don't lose hope,nor be sad."

represent the allah using a variable called glorious. Then compose your message and represent it with a new variable called message. Print your message.

```py
glorious="Allah"

print(f'{glorious} said,"don't lose hope,nor be sad."' )
```

But I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes must be escaped with a backslash when enclosed in single quotes:

```
print(f'{glorious} said,"don\'t lose hope,nor be sad."')
```

You can also use a docstring with triple quotes instead to decrease the likelihood that you would need to escape anything in the literal:

```
print(f'''{glorious} said,"don't lose hope,nor be sad."''')
```

Comment: Heads up that the second is just a [triple-quoted string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). A docstring is specifically *any* string at the head of a module, class or function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the double quotes within the string:

```
glorious = 'allah'

print(glorious + " said, \"don't lose hope, nor be sad.\"")
```

You get a syntax error because for example if you do

```
print(glorious + "said, " don't lose hope, nor be sad.)
```

1. the string is only `"said, "`
2. python doesn't know what (don) is
3. the string (`'t lose hope, nor be sad.`) is incomplete